# How to get uploaded image location url by cmb2

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a image add file field in by cmb2 metabox like

```
$FF_side_settings->add_field( array(
        'name'    => 'Upload background image',
        'desc'    => 'Upload an image or enter an URL.',
        'id'      => 'ff_image_upload',
        'type'    => 'file',
        // Optional:
        'options' => array(
            'url' => true, 
            'add_upload_file_text' => 'Add image' 
        ),
    ) );
```

I want to get the image location and show the value in my div image background-url

```
<div class="fun-bg " style='background-image: url("'.$image.'");'>
```

I used `wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ff_image_upload', 1 ), 'medium' );` for that but i faild  to do that. can someone please help me to find out where is my problem please and fix that............

Comment: is this key 'gsff_image_upload' exists ?

Comment: ya that is the   the field id, i carelessly  wrote gs, i reedit my post  now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK `wp_get_attachment_image()` returns image tag:

```
<img src="image_src" ... />
```

in your case you need echo function return

```
<div class="fun-bg">
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ff_image_upload', 1 ), 'medium' ); ?>
</div>
```

or get only src attribute, not image tag himself.

EDIT:
I installed this plugin and did some tests with images metabox.

So when you add image through this plugin it creates two records in postmeta table. First is with metakey `ff_image_upload_id` with value id of the post (52 in my case), and second is with key `ff_image_upload` and value = image_path.

`get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ff_image_upload', 1 )` will return image path - `http://host/site-name/wp-content/uploads/year/month/name.jpg`

This is path to the original image, not 'medium', 'thumbnail' or something like

`get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ff_image_upload_id', 1 )` will return post_id (52).

If you want to use `wp_get_attachment_image()` to display image directly, you **must** append the post id with `id` so you must use it like this:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ff_image_upload_id', 1 ), 'medium' ); ?>
```

If you want the `url` of the image, this will return the `url` of the `medium` image:

```
<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ff_image_upload_id', 1 ), 'medium' )[0]; ?>
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)